Delete file from the directory which is not in the list
Using the ForEach-Object operator I get a string from the list $allImages that is not in the hashtable $wImages. Then I have to delete every file with any extension whose name contains this string in $imagesdir.
$imagesdir = "C:\images"
$allImages | ForEach-Object {
    if (-not $wImages.ContainsKey($_)) { 
        Write-Output $_ 
    }
}

What operators should I use to remove the files instead of Write-Output $_?

What if more than 1 string from $allImages is identified? Do you want to remove all files with any of the strings in the name?

yes, I want to remove all files with any of string in the name. If the name of the file doesn't contain the string I need to keep the file.

You'll want to call the Get-ChildItem cmdlet to discover the files in $imagesDir, then use a string comparison operator (the -like wildcard operator or the -match regex operator) to determine whether the string is found in the name, and then finally pipe the resulting set of files to Remove-Item.
Additionally, simplify your code with Where-Object, a cmdlet designed to filter input objects, so:
... |ForEach-Object { if ($condition){ $_ } } 

... becomes:
... |Where-Object { $condition }

Let's give it a try:
# start by constructing a regex pattern from the list of filter strings
$filterStrings = $allImages |Where-Object { -not $wImages.ContainsKey($_) } |ForEach-Object { [regex]::Escape($_) }

if ($filterStrings) {
  $filterPattern = $filterStrings -join '|'

  # now let's discover the files in the image directory and filter them using the pattern
  $filesToRemove = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $imagesDir -File |Where-Object {
    $_.BaseName -match $filterPattern
  }
}

The synthetic BaseName property will give you the current file's name without the extension - if you want to search the full file name, use $_.Name instead of $_.BaseName
Now that you've discovered the files you need to delete, go ahead and invoke Remove-Item:
$filesToRemove |Remove-Item


the script works only one time. If I run the script second time (after removing the necessary files) it removes all files in the folder...

@Shud I mean, it still works, you just don't have any files left to remove :)

I would say, it works correct first time (it deletes necessary files), when I run it second time - it works not correct, because it deletes everything, but it should keep the files, because necessary file were deleted before...

@Shud Ahh I see what you mean, I've updated it to guard against running out of candidate filter strings now :)

Note: I'm working under the assumption the strings represented by the key names in the Hashtable are PARTIAL strings: a key named 2023 should thus match a filename "The Largest Baby Beer Battle in Year 2023 of the Current Calendar.whatever"
# the values are completely irrelevant in this case.   
$allImages = @{
    String_1                                   = 'value 1'
    String_2                                   = 'value 3'
    ThisIsMyKey                                = 44
    '0'                                        = $true
    'by the hoary hoggards of the Vishanti!|!' = $null
}


# This also Escape all the Key names.   
# You can obviously combine these steps in one line, but it's better to keep
# them easier to read.   
$ArrayFromHash = $allImages.Keys | ForEach-Object { [regex]::Escape($_) }
$StringFromArray = $ArrayFromHash -join '|'
$RegexFilter = ".*($StringFromArray).*"

# result is 
#    .*(String_1|0|by\ the\ hoary\ hoggards\ of\ the\ Vishanti!\|!|ThisIsMyKey|String_2).*


Get-ChildItem -file -LiteralPath $imagesdir |  
    # this will match and thus send to Remove-Item only the names not matching
    # $RegxFilter.    
    Where-Object -Property BaseName -NotMatch -Value $RegexFilter | 
    # remove -WhatIf if it's working as intended.   
    Remove-Item -WhatIf

